# Title page using begin{titlepage} Journal-like style

Tags: titles

I am trying to make a titlepage similar to the one below. However I am having a few problems regarding getting dagger, and star as footnotes. Also, when I tried to writer author like in the image (same line with space between), I have some "issues" because I have centering and one of the names has 4 + 4 letters and the other has 7 + 7, therefore it seems sort of unbalanced... Thanks [image: Replicate this]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}%set line spacing
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=5cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}%gir avsnitt iuten\\
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for the horizontal lines, change thickness here

\center % Center everything on the page

 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING SECTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\textsc{Business School - Thesis}\\[2.6cm] % Name of university/college
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%\HRule \\
{ \LARGE \bfseries  Do the Financial Markets Trust XXX?:} \\[0.5cm] 
{\Large \bfseries A Macro-Finance Model of the Term Structure}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AUTHOR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\textsc{Authors:}\\
 Author1 $^\dag$\\
  Author2$^\ddag$\\[0.8cm]%Department of Economics  %Department of Financial Economics
\textsc{Supervisor:}\\Institute sup.\\[1cm]


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DATE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\today\\[1cm] % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise
\hrule
\abstract{From a macroeconomic perspective, the short-term interest rate is a policy instrument under the direct control of the central bank, which adjusts the rate to achieve its economic stabilization goals.}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LOGO SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\vfill % Filling the rest of the page with whitespace
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to achieve all of the layout elements that you want with minimal manual fiddling using LaTeX's built in titleblock typesetting. You can use `\\` to insert new lines or white space inside `\title`, `\author`, and `\date` and incorporate the business school, supervisor, and institution information into these.

LaTeX automatically uses star/dagger footnote symbols within its titleblock, and ensures that the author block is in the center of the page (even if one author's name is longer).

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{
\textsc{Business School -- Thesis}\\[2.6cm]
{\LARGE \bfseries Project Title}\\{\Large\bfseries Project Subtitle}\thanks{Paper footnotes.}
}

\author{
First Author' Long Name\thanks{First author's footnotes go here.}\\Podang U. 
\and 
Second Author\thanks{Second author's footnotes go here.} \\Potato U.
}

\date{
\textsc{Supervisor:} Supervisor's Name\\[1em]
\today
}

%----------------------------------

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\hrule

\begin{abstract}
Abstract text goes here.
\end{abstract}
\vfill
\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thats fair enough, but I need the additional title for which business school I am graduating, furthermore I want a line to go across the page before the abstract... which is why i used titlepage environment

Comment: and supervisor...

Comment: @MAT-TEX I edited the example to include these elements.

Comment: @Ubiquitous Can you add any more information other than just your code to give context and explain how it addresses the question/problem?

Comment: I edited it a bit further and now I am satisfied. Used \setlength{\droptitle}{-10em} to adjust the title further..